# What is recommended response to resource failure for cloud witness in FCI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, clustering

I'm looking at an FCI on an Azure VM. This is a test setup. In the failover cluster manager when I right click on cloud witness resource and click on properties, then click on policies, under Response to resource failure the setting value is: If resource fails, attempt restart on current node.

I find this odd. Why should cloud witness resource failure cause restart? Can anyone explain me about this default configuration and if this needs changing.

Update:
I looked up this setting on couple of other Azure as well as on Prem SQL clusters and even if the witness is an on Prem file share, it has the same setting configured as above. So what exactly does restart mean here? Will it cause restart of file server?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] under Response to resource failure the setting value is: If resource fails, attempt restart on current node.

> I find this odd. Why should cloud witness resource failure cause restart?

If the resource fails, the default response is to attempt and restart the *resource*, not the node/server. Restarting the resource attempts to bootstrap it from the beginning, which could help with any runtime specific issues that had occurred by starting with a clean state, giving it the best chance at succeeding to come online.

This is a configurable option, as noted, if you would rather something else happen you're free to set it the way you see fit. You only need to change it if you don't want that action to occur, which is going to be a *personal* decision based on the environment and configuration.

Comment: But the resource here is the cloud witness. Does it actually restart the witness server?

Comment: @variable No it restarts the witness resource, `the default response is to attempt and restart the resource`.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what does it mean to restart a resource. I understand restart a server but not sure whats restart a resource mean. I think this applies to the wsfc nodes and not the witness.

Comment: When you restart a resource, you take the resource offline, and attempt to bring it online again. The actual instructions to do this will change depending on each resource's implemented clustering dll.

Comment: Yes but I'm guessing that resource means the node. And not the file share. Am I right?

Comment: To quote myself: `the default response is to attempt and restart the resource, not the node/server.`